# Content of fancybox's displayed slowly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm building a website.In the website I show a fancybox when post data to server as the code below.

```
function showfancybox()
   {
     $.fancybox($('#popup-processing-senddata'), {
        padding: 0,
        closeBtn: false,
        helpers: {
            overlay:
            {
                opacity: 0.8,
                css: { 'background-color': '#11619d' },
                closeClick: false
            }
        }
    });


    SendDataToServer = function () {
        if (this.enableNextButton()) {

            showfancybox();

            var hasError = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < this.Rows().length; i++) 
            {

                   $.ajax({
                    async:false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/AddCustomer/SendData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: JSON.stringify(rowData),
                    success: function (datareturn) 
                    {
                       if (datareturn != '') {
                            $.fancybox.close();
                            showCustomError(datareturn);
                            hasError = true;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        // Boil the ASP.NET AJAX error down to JSON.
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");

                        // Display the specific error raised by the server (e.g. not a
                        // valid value for Int32, or attempted to divide by zero).
                        $.fancybox.close();
                        showCustomError(err);
                        hasError = true;
                    }
                });
             }
}
```

I'm facing an issue.When submit data the fancybox only show an overlay the content of the fancybox has a delay 15 seconds.I need the content of fancybox has delay less than 2 seconds.Can anyone help me?
Thanks inadvance

Comment: it seems that your are calling `showfancybox()` from within `showfancybox()`... maybe your delay is because that loop.

Comment: Oh,no I'm not calling showfancybox() from within showfancybox().the cause is that in my site I have to set async:false it can not be changed to asysnc:true